# Select sampling frequency to closed loop control in a DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, control-system, sampling

For a DC-DC converter in current mode control the control variable is the inductor's current, which at steady state is periodic. which is the ratio between the switching frequency and the sampling frequency to use this type of control? By the Nyquist–Shannon theorem the sampling period should be at most half of the signal period, it is that enough?  but even them it will only apply for steady state, for the transient the sampling frequency should be even higher. Am I missing something?[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Do you want to monitor the inductor current for the purpose of switching transistors or you want to make a current control loop?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I want to make a current-mode control loop. I don't get how can I improve the transient response only  knowing the average  inductor's current at a lower frequency than fs.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to consider the Nyquist frequency if you want to be able to **fully reconstruct** your sampled signal.

Do you want to fully reconstruct the shape of the inductor current ? I think not, you only need an average value of the coil current. So if you time-average that current (this can be done by using a filter) you then only need a much lower sampling rate to measure that average. As long as that sample rate is sufficiently faster than the speed of the DCDC converter's voltage or current control loop it will work fine.

Notice how the converter's switching frequency does not directly relate to the speed or sampling rate of the control loop !

Comment: In that case, is there any advantage in measuring the current at inductor and not at the load? the output current is already the average

Comment: If measuring at the load side was practical then probably that could be a solution. I've not seen that done though (for voltage regulating converters), what is usually done there is that the current is measured through the switch in series with the inductor. But for a current controlled DCDC measuring the current through a shunt resistors in series with the output is more common.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez What is the position of inductor and what of the load? If your intent is to control a current trugh motor, then you should measure the current at the output of the bridge.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Is a buck converter with a resistive load.